# Custom message with Regex assert

Tags: validation, symfony, annotations

I have a problem displaying a custom message with Regex assert. It worked good for any other assert but not Regex.

Here is my assert :

```
@Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern = "/^[0-9]{1,6}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"),
 *     message = "I want to display Bad value"
 * )
```

The validation works but the message is a symfony default one. Why is that ? What do I miss ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see you have a bracket in wrong position.
try:

```
* @Assert\Regex(
*     pattern = "/^[0-9]{1,6}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/",
*     message = "I want to display Bad value"
* )
```

Comment: sorry I did not copy everything.. I have the last bracket of course

Comment: You still have one bracket too much, there is no need for bracket after ``pattern = "/^[0-9]{1,6}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/",``